# how to set custom rating bars height and width without cut and stretch.in andoroid

Tags: android, ratingbar

I am using 2 custom images for rating bar. but either the height is cutting of or extra line to the bottom is showing.cannot add fixed width and height

Comment: Add some code here else no one will able to help you.

Comment: i couldnt add any code . i amnew to this site,..when ever i try to add code.it is showing error